# How to "upsert" an array/nested field when issuing update mutation in Graphcool / GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphcool

I have a `Post` type than has a `tag` field which can be associated with many `Tag` entries (man-to-many relationship). The issue I am running into is when updating a `Post` - I need to both create and associate new `Tag`'s for tags that do not yet exist, while preserving the existing `Post`->`Tag` relationships. Basically, what I am looking for is something akin to an `upsert` when issuing a mutation update on a nested one-to-many field.

Here is my schema:

```
type Post @model {
  createdAt: DateTime!
  createdBy: User @relation(name: "PostsByUser")
  description: String @defaultValue(value: "''")
  id: ID! @isUnique
  tags: [Tag!]! @relation(name: "TagsOfPost")
  ...
}

type Tag @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  tag: String!
  createdBy: User @relation(name: "TagsByUser")
  createdAt: DateTime!
  posts: [Post!]! @relation(name: "TagsOfPost")
}
```

This mutation works to update a `Post` and add *new* tags, but overwrite all of the existing values in the `Post`'s `tag` field:

```
mutation updatePost(
  $id: ID!
  $createdById: ID!
  $timestamp: DateTime!
  $description: String
  $tags: [PosttagsTag!]!
) {
  updatePost(
    id: $id
    createdById: $createdById
    timestamp: $timestamp
    description: $description
    tags: $tags
  ) {
    id
    timestamp
    description
    tags {
      id
      tag
    }
    createdBy {
      id
      username
    }
  }
}
```

I came across [this post](https://www.graph.cool/forum/t/how-do-i-add-an-array-of-objects-to-a-mutation-in-apollo-react/365/6) by [@marktani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176596/marktani) but it's not clear how to implement the *combined* method he outlines:

> **Combined**
>   You can also use tags and tagsIds in the same mutation, this would connect the new Tutorial node to all the tags in tagsIds and connect it to the new tags in tags. This is what you want to do if you want to only allow tags with a unique text, so for a new Tutorial, there will likely be some tags that already exists, and some that need to be created.

Is it currently impossible to do this with one mutation? Would a second mutation be required after updating the post with new tags to re-establish the associations between the `Post` and existing `Tag` ids, i.e., having to repeatedly call `addToTagsOfPost(tagsTagId: ID!
postsPostId: ID!)`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so [there is currently a Graphcool bug](https://github.com/graphcool/framework/issues/1288) where passing in both `tags` and `tagsIds` to the mutation will create and associate *newly created* `Tags` but will not add the `tagsIds` associations to *existing* `Tags`. I posted an issue on Graphcool's GitHub repo and they have acknowledged it - https://github.com/graphcool/framework/issues/1288